# ROS/C++: unresolved includes cannot be fixed in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, ros, catkin

I am new to eclipse, I followed this tutorial: https://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse, I successfully made a ROS package, generated a project in 'build' folder. It can be loaded, but 'Unresolved inclusion' appears when I am trying to include headers in my C++ code.

The 'preprocessor Include Paths' section in properties -> C/C++ General disappeared in newer version of eclipse. What should I do?

Besides, I have studied programming and CS for a long time already, but I personally struggle a lot in INSTALLATION, COMPILATION, SETTING OF ENVIRONMENT, etc. Where can I find updated resources for those problems? They are really discouraging for me, and I am just wasting my time dealing with settings and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Possible hotfix to your problem might be:

1. Look for CMakeLists.txt file within your project
2. add `add_inlucde_directories(path/to/missing/includes)`

However as long as you're new to eclipse, in case you really need IDE I would strongly recommend changing to `CLion` (there is a community version) as it has 'out of the box' support for the `CMake` which is used within `ROS`.

Moreover a better way might be using some text editor with plugins implementing IDE useful stuff like auto-completion e.t.c. and using terminal and ROS utilities for building/running your projects (`catkin`, `rosrun`, `roslaunch` e.t.c.).

One more advice which helped me a lot in overcoming that SETTING OF ENVIRONMENT problem is using docker (though using gui stuff makes it painful, still it's possible).

You might find it useful reading about:

CMake https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html
which should give you basic idea of what CMake is.

ROS intro tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials
you don't really need IDE to complete this tutorial so maybe you'll find a way of text editor + ros utilities from terminal more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and I shall apply your tips! I should study some documentation first.